# Output comment_author in array

Tags: functions, array, comment-form

In functions.php for part of custom comments, I have the following echoed array as the link to respond to a previous comment:

```
<?php echo comment_reply_link(array(
"before" => " <span class=\"comment-reply-link\">", 
"after" => "</span>", 
"reply_text" => "Reply to this comment", 
"depth" => $depth, 
"max_depth" => $args["max_depth"] 
));  
?>
```

I am trying to get the link to replace the word "this" with the `comment_author()`.

I am a novice at php, and have tried every syntax I can think of but have failed.
I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to make the following work.

```
<?php echo comment_reply_link(array(
"before" => " <span class=\"comment-reply-link\">", 
"after" => "</span>", 
"reply_text" => "Reply to " . echo comment_author() here . "'s comment", 
"depth" => $depth, 
"max_depth" => $args["max_depth"] 
));  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

I was trying to call the wrong wp function.

By using `get_comment_author()` instead of `comment_author()` the link displays as desired.